# Disappearing characters Xelatex?

Tags: xetex, biblatex

I've noticed that when I compile my .tex file (xelatex -- biber -- xelatex), that several characters (like π and Λ) become missing.  Here is what I'm getting:

[1] P. del Amo Sanchez et al. ``Searches for the baryon- and lepton-number vi-
olating decays B0+c −, B−−, and B− ̄−''. In: Phys.Rev. D83 (2011), p. 091101.

[2] J.P. Lees et al. ``Cross Sections for the Reactions e+e−K+K−+−, K+K−00, and K+K−K+K− Measured Using Initial-State Radiation''. In: (2011). * Temporary entry *.

This is what the titles should look like:

[1] Searches for the baryon- and lepton-number violating decays B0→Λ+cℓ−, B−→Λℓ−, and B−→Λˉℓ−.
(See http://inspirebeta.net/record/884880)

[2] Cross Sections for the Reactions e+e−→K+K−π+π−,K+K−π0π0, and K+K−K+K− Measured Using Initial-State Radiation. 
(See http://inspirebeta.net/record/892684)

Here is my .tex file:

```
\listfiles

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode,realscripts,unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Bitstream Cyberbit} % or any font on your system
\setsansfont{Asana Math} % or any font on your system

\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{doi=false, eprint=false}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{Lees:2011zi,
  author         = "Lees, J.P. and others",
  title          = "{Cross Sections for the Reactions $e^+e^- \to K^+ K^-
                    \pi^+\pi^-,\, K^+ K^- \pi^0\pi^0$, and $K^+ K^- K^+ K^-$
                    Measured Using Initial-State Radiation}",
  collaboration  = "The BABAR Collaboration",
  year           = "2011",
  note           = "* Temporary entry *",
  eprint         = "1103.3001",
  archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
  primaryClass   = "hep-ex",
}

 @article{:2011us,
  author         = "del Amo Sanchez, P. and others",
  title          = "{Searches for the baryon- and lepton-number violating
                    decays $B^0\rightarrow\Lambda_c^+\ell^-$,
                    $B^-\rightarrow\Lambda\ell^-$, and
                    $B^-\rightarrow\bar{\Lambda}\ell^-$}",
  collaboration  = "BABAR Collaboration",
  journal        = "Phys.Rev.",
  volume         = "D83",
  pages          = "091101",
  doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevD.83.091101",
  year           = "2011",
  eprint         = "1101.3830",
  archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
  primaryClass   = "hep-ex",
 }


\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should say `\setmathfont{Asana Math}`, rather than `\setsansfont`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a mistake in your input: it should be

```
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
```

and not `\setsansfont`.

Comment: Just one last thing...how can I hide the "note" variable? I tried \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{doi=false, eprint=false,note=false} but this didn't seem to work.

Comment: That should be another question for **biblatex** gurus.